# how to copy input type hidden value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to copy input type hidden value in javascript
**HTML**

```
    <input class="d-none" type="text" value="my name is vikram" id="idCopyReferralLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clsCopyClipboardText" id="lnkReferralUrlCopySigned">COPY LINK</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".clsCopyClipboardText").on("click", function() {
            var input = document.getElementById("idCopyReferralLink");
            input.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            input.blur();
            $(this).html("COPIED");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Following this code

Comment: you can't select hidden input. you could clone it out, use a lib, or just add `input.type="text";` before the execCommand, then `input.type="hidden";` after it. the jank flash should be un-noticable.

Answer (score 0):

Just show the input, and then select , copy and hide it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clsCopyClipboardText").on("click", function() {
        var input = document.getElementById("idCopyReferralLink");

        // js
        input.setAttribute("type","text");
        input.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        input.setAttribute("type","hidden");

        // jquery if you need this
        /*
            $("#idCopyReferralLink").attr("type","text");
            $("#idCopyReferralLink")[0].select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            $("#idCopyReferralLink").attr("type","hidden");
        */
        input.blur();
        $(this).html("COPIED");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<input class="d-none" type="hidden" value="my name is vikram" id="idCopyReferralLink">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clsCopyClipboardText" id="lnkReferralUrlCopySigned">COPY LINK</a>
```